# objc_retain EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address0Xf1edd142)

Tags: ios

I use `GCDAsyncSocket` in my project,in `GCDAsyncSocketDelegate` , I receive message and process it, but I receive objc_retain EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address0Xf1edd142) in the following code

```
if (self.currentCommand.delegate != nil && [self.currentCommand.delegate 
    respondsToSelector:@selector(commandSuccessed:didReceiveData:)]) {

    [self.currentCommand.delegate commandSuccessed:self.currentCommand      
        didReceiveData:result];

}
```

it work well in Simulator，but crash in my device;

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?
Or is usually what causes this error?

Comment: Are you using an external (static) library? If so, make sure it is compiled using the exact same settings your app is using.

Comment: Try enable zombie objects or track zombie by instruments.